# Error: Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of SOBJECT:Purchase_Order_Details__c does not match domain of foreign key at line 19 column 77

Tags: apex, class

I just started programming in apex, so I will appreciate your help in this case.
This class should allow me to get the bundle_Items from bundle object where Bundle__c =(Here is the result of the 'values', which returning the correct Ids, I already tested it). I don't know if I am doing something wrong in the second query, or there might be another approach for the IN: values.

"Error: Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of SOBJECT:Purchase_Order_Details__c does not match domain of foreign key at line 19 column 79"

Thank you so much in advance!

```
public class  PO_Vendor_Controller_BundleItems {

    public ApexPages.StandardController std2;
    public List<o_Bundle__c> PODetails2 {get; set;}  
    Public List<Purchase_Order_Details__c> values {get;set;}    

    public PO_Vendor_Controller_BundleItems (ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl2){
        std2=stdCtrl2; 
        List<Purchase_Order_Details__c> values = [SELECT ProductId__c 
                                                  FROM Purchase_Order_Details__c 
                                                  WHERE PO_ID__c =:std2.getId()]; 
        String[] contractIDs = new string[values.size()]; 

        for (integer i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
             contractIDs[i] = values[i].ProductId__c;
        }
        PODetails2 = [SELECT Bundle_Item__c 
                      FROM o_Bundle__c 
                      WHERE Bundle__c IN:contractIDs ]; 
    }//END init(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl2)

}//END PO_Vendor_Controller_BundleItems
```

---

**Update** - above `Constructor` updated

Comment: What is the field type of Bundle__c on o_Bundle__c?  I suspect it is lookup to o_Bundle__c right?  I tested a similar query from case to user and it worked fine.  I usually use Ids instead of whole objects when filtering like this, but from the test I ran it should work fine as long as Bundle__c is a relationship to o_Bundle__c.

Comment: It is a lookup. I found a solution in case others are having the same issue:

Comment: public PO_Vendor_Controller_BundleItems (ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl2)  
   
   { 
    std2=stdCtrl2;
      
    List<Purchase_Order_Details__c> values  = [SELECT ProductId__c  FROM Purchase_Order_Details__c WHERE PO_ID__c =:std2.getId()];
     
     String[] contractIDs = new string[values.size()];
       
        for (integer i=0; i<values.size(); i++)
        {
           contractIDs[i] = values[i].ProductId__c ;
       }
        
  PODetails2 = [SELECT Bundle_Item__c FROM o_Bundle__c WHERE Bundle__c  IN:contractIDs  ];
 

    }
   }

Comment: What line is causing the error?   (what's going on in the ErrorLine?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In where clause you have used field 'PO_ID__c'. Make sure that this field is lookup or master-detail field and this field looks up to the SObject mentioned in standardController attribute on VF page.